# How does VUE engine evaluates attribute code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eval, sandbox

In VUE it is possible to write full JS expressions inside attributes. For example for the `<div>` below,

```js
var app = new Vue({ el: '#app', data: { message: 'Hello Vue!', num: 3 } })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="message"/>
  <div v-html="'abc' + ' ' + message + ' ' + 2 * num"></div>
</div>
```

The result is `abc HelloVue! 6`.

---

**How does VUE calculates this result? Some kind of sandboxed `eval`?**

**Where in the [VUE's repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue) does this calculation happen?**

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue  You can explore the repo when you have questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole template is compiled into a big render function in JavaScript. Attribute and prop bindings are evaluated inline when the vnode for that element is rendered.

This template:

```
<div v-html="'abc' + ' ' + message + ' ' + 2 * num"></div>
```

is compiled into something like:

```js
vnode = _c('div', {
  domProps: {
    "innerHTML": _s('abc' + ' ' + message + ' ' + 2 * num)
  }
})
```

The entire render function is wrapped in a [`with(this) { ... }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement so that properties on the component instance can be written like `message` instead of `this.message`.

There is no `eval()` happening, it is executed directly as if you had written the render function by hand. The template compiler code may use `new Function()` *at compile time* to check that the syntax is valid, but during execution of the app no such sandboxing is performed.

[This online Vue 2 template compiler](https://vuejs-tips.github.io/compiler/#PGRpdiB2LWh0bWw9IidhYmMnICsgJyAnICsgbWVzc2FnZSArICcgJyArIDIgKiBudW0iPjwvZGl2Pg==) shows how templates are compiled into render functions.

Vue 3 compiles templates differently and is more optimized. Use [Vue Template Explorer](https://vue-next-template-explorer.netlify.app) to experiment with it.

Comment: Very interesting use of `with`. I would say it is pretty useful yet not very well known.